# This Mac can't connect to iCloud because of a problem with myEmail popup

Tags: macos, icloud

I just restarted my mac. The internet here is spotty. I saw the popup below. I really could not care less if I can connect to iCloud at the moment of a particular startup or not. I just don't want popups. Is there any way I can get rid of it, permanently? Hopefully not by disabling iCloud; I'm sure there was a reason I enabled it; likely to get rid of some other popup somewhere.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, there's not an issue with your email. It is showing that to identify the account that is being problematic, which in this case is the Apple ID with that email associated with it.

Answer (score 4):

[Chris Haertel's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/267390/chris-haertel) answer to [a different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305847/icloud-connection-after-upgrade-to-high-sierra) also works here, as evidenced by [an Apple Discussions thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8274333):

> In your user folder, go to `~/Library/Keychains/` (hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key when clicking in the <kbd>Go</kbd> menu in Finder to show the Library folder).
>
> In that folder, there are the regular keychains, plus some folders with monstrously long names like `F2555809-AAC0-5CFA-BEF6-57BB56345BIUR` or some such.
>
> I deleted those folders only.

After restarting, you may need to log into iCloud again, but the persistent popup and "An unknown error occurred" messages should be gone for good.

Answer (score 3):

I've been dealing with this same problem for a few days now (pretty annoying). The last thing I tried was to un-check every iCloud service that was enabled, sign out of iCloud and then sign back in. So far it seems to be OK, I'll just try it a bit more to see if the message pops up again.

To do so, just go to your iCloud settings in the System Preferences. This will open a setting windows much like this one.

[image: iCloud Settings Services]

Once there you have to deselect every service enabled and then proceed to `Sign Out`

You may be asked to save a copy of your iCloud data such as Contacts, Calendars, Pictures, etc. You may uncheck the services you dont want to save a copy and then just click `Continue` or `Keep` if you have selected any of the data to keep.

If you want to re-connect with your iCloud user account (or a new one) you'll have to select `Sign In` and then just proceed as requested.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Wouldn’t you instead click account details and verify the password is indeed correct? Then clearing the keychain of nay old / wrong passwords for this account seems prudent if the error persists. That avoids needing to sign out

Comment: @bmike When opening iCloud preferences and entering the correct password, you just get the "An unknown error occurred" message.