# iCloud connection after upgrade to High Sierra

Tags: itunes, icloud, high-sierra

Nov 13th I upgraded to High Sierra. During the boot proces the password for iCloud is asked (I think I entered it correctly). However a spinner started spinning (basically forever). So I shutdown the Mac (button back) and rebooted. Systems works okay. Except for iCloud.

Update:
I managed to delete my previous accounts towards iCloud. However I'm not able to connect/recreate accounts again.

iCloud asks for UID/PW and after that a never stopping spinner occurs.
No difference for wrong UID or Password.

I checked the UID/PW for correctness using different devices/websites.
Also tried other AppleId's.

What can I do to get this working again?

Comment: Try creating a new account (for diagnostics) and sign in there.  If it works, the profile you are using is corrupted somehow.

Comment: Tried that also. Both with existing and nonexisting accounts. Totally stuck. Apple=

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and fixed it as follows:

In your user folder, go to `~/Library/Keychains/` (hold down the "option" key when clicking in the "Go to" menu to show the Library folder).

In that folder, there are the regular keychains, plus some folders with monstrously long names like `F2555809-AAC0-5CFA-BEF6-57BB56345BIUR` or some such.

I deleted those folders only.

After a restart, my email accounts and everything else had been logged out and the system requested a log-in password to my Apple ID. I was able to re-enter it, and since then, all iCloud services have worked fine, including Photos, iCloud Drive, iMessage, etc. - even text replacement is now syncing fine.

Comment: I tried different things. Not sure if this was one of them. Reinstalled MacOs fully, that did not resolve it. After that reformatted the harddrive and after a brand new installation everything works again. Thanks for your comment, maybe someone can use it! For me it is to late.

Comment: This works to fix the "This Mac can't connect to iCloud because of a problem with $email" popup as well – see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364485/)